# After installing windows_curse, it shows ImportError: cannot import name 'resizeterm' from 'curses'

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, curses, pv3d

I am testing pv3d and have downloaded packages already. In testing, I've downloaded it using `pip install windows_curses`, but it displayed `ImportError: cannot import name 'resizeterm' from 'curses'` when I was running `from curses import resizeterm`, what should I do to solve that?

The requirement of windows curses has already satisfied, here I would like to imort curses normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're not importing the right object. It should be

```py
from curses import resize_term
```

and ***not***

```py
from curses import resizeterm
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it has been successfully solved.